# Does the engine provide the lift of the aircraft?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, classical-mechanics, fluid-dynamics, lift

In the absence of the effect of natural wind, a stationary aircraft will not move without the thrust of the engine, there will be no velocity without movement, and there will be no lift without velocity. So, in this case, the engine provides the lift of the aircraft. Am I correct?

[image: Objects and Inclined plane]

The wing has an angle of attack, so although the engine pushes the aircraft horizontally, it still produces upward force. It's like pushing an object horizontally on an inclined plane.

Gliders are powered by gravity, so in this case, gravity is the engine. So basically, the engine provides the lift of the aircraft.

A glider needs initial velocity to fly. How does this initial velocity come from? How can there be lift without this initial velocity? How can there be lift without initial velocity?

Answer (score 3):

It would not be correct to state that the engine provides the lift of an aircraft any more than it would be correct to say that hydrogen provides the force I use to press keys on my keyboard (after all, all of the energy came from the sun, which is fusing hydrogen).

Lift is the upward force on an aircraft, opposing gravity.  This is typically aerodynamic forces caused by there being lower pressure above a wing and higher pressure below it.  In a helicopter, lift is caused by the rotor which is powered by the engine.  In an airplane, the engines are mounted in the wrong direction to provide lift (with the notable exceptions of a [few](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hUNJTAybCQQ) [aircraft](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zW28Mb1YvwY) which were specifically designed to provide lift with engine thrust).

**Aerodynamic** lift *is* dependent on velocity.  You need relative velocity between the air and the wing to get aerodynamic lift.  I think that's where you're linking lift and the engine, but its more correct to link the lift and the velocity together.  You wont have aerodynamic lift without velocity, but you can have it without an engine.  This is what a glider is.  We typically do not say "gravity is the glider's engine" except in the most loose of wordings.  We say that gliders do not have engines.  You can get the velocity from any source.  For example, gliders often get their initial velocity by being pulled with a tow cable.  Hang gliders often start on a cliff, and jump off, letting gravity increase their air speed before pulling into level flight.

Where the engine comes in is combatting drag.  All sources aerodynamic lift come with a parasitic drag -- drag we didn't want, but we can't get rid of.  This drag opposes forward motion, decreasing velocity.  As velocity drops, so does lift.  An engine is one way this can be solved.  An engine can cause a *forward* thrust force which can cancel out this drag force, permitting a vehicle to continue flying with the same lift it had before.

This then lets us explain how gliders stay aloft.  They must be constantly gliding slightly downward with respect to the air to keep up their speed.  They have no engine, so the only way they can get the force to combat drag is from gravity.  However, if they can find a thermal (a rising column of hot air), they can hang out inside that, letting the heat of the ground below power their upward flight.

And, incidentally, most flying vehicles have far more lift than drag.  A very important number for the performance of aircraft is the [Lift-to-Drag ratio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lift-to-drag_ratio), or L/D.  This captures how much lift the aircraft can create for every unit of aerodynamic drag.  Most jet airliners today have a lift to drag ratio of 15:1 or so, which means that a 800,000 pound 747 needs only around 53,000 pounds of thrust to combat the drag and keep it flying straight and level.  A glider can hit 70:1 (as L/D is a very dominant number for gliders)

Comment: You're using the engine of another plane to lift the glider, so your glider still needs an engine. Without the thrust of the engine to give the aircraft an initial speed, it is impossible for the aircraft to generate lift. Of course, I mean when there's no wind (no power beyond the engine).

Comment: My problem has a premise, that is, the lift of the plane taking off from the ground.

Comment: So you can think that way, which is why I mentioned the idea that I can start from the premise that all of my actions are caused by stellar fusion in our sun.  However, it is a very difficult way of thinking about things which is not typically used.  As a case example, consider a meteor.  Meteors can generate lift.  But what is their engine?

Comment: Their engine isn't "gravity."  Gravity only plays a small part in the story of what happens to a meteor.  Most of its energy came from the fact that it was hurtling through outer space at an astonishing speed.  If you choose to think of lift being a consequence of aerodynamic forces, its easy to conceptualize.  If you think of lift as being a consequence of the aggregation process of our solar system and the potential energy put into it by the big bang, it gets really hard.

Comment: (those last two should be a rephrasing of the comments I deleted while you were replying.  I wasn't a fan of the wording I had before)

Comment: The approach you describe also gets tricky in the case of planes which launch from an elevated position, such as hang gliders launching from cliffs or flying foxes leaping between trees.  In those cases the only source of energy which could be thought of as an "engine" is the energy put into the airplane/animal before it took the sky and generated lift.  Or consider the steam catapault of an aircraft carrier, which puts all of its energy into the plane before the plane leaves the deck.

Comment: As shown in my figure, under gravity, the object slides down the slope. Where does the lifting force come from? Why doesn't it fall directly through the slope under the action of gravity?

Comment: That is another question.  Its a more common one, so if you do some research you'll find some great videos explaining it.  Long story short, wings are shaped such that if they are put in a moving air stream (i.e. flying), the air above the wing is at a lower pressure than the air below it.  This difference causes the air to push the plane upwards similar to how water is drawn up a straw when you drink.

Comment: You explain the slide of the object on the Inclined plane. It's the same thing as a glider.

Answer (score 2):

You seem to have a couple misconceptions here.

It's the air moving relative to the wing that provides the lift to the aircraft.  Just because it's *typically* done with an engine, it doesn't mean that's the only mechanism. As dmckee mentioned, gliders are an obvious example where you can obtain lift without any engine or thrust.  You just utilize the relative velocity between the air and your gliders wings; and can still get enough lift to increase your altitude.

In the block hitting an inclined plane example, it's similar.  When you push a block horizontally on an inclined plane, the force of your pushing *doesn't* move the block upwards.  It cannot, it is a forwards force.  What moves the block upwards is the *reaction* force of the inclined plane.  It's the ground pushing back up that has an upward force on the block.

The upwards force doesn't really come from the forwards force in either scenario; it comes from the thing that the forwards force is causing an interaction with.  But in either case, the forwards force isn't required; just some relative movement.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/101797/discussion-on-answer-by-jmac-does-the-engine-provide-the-lift-of-the-aircraft).

Answer (score 2):

> So, in this case, the engine provides the lift of the aircraft. am I correct?

No, you are not generally correct. The engine provides thrust. The only time that it provides lift is if the thrust is oriented vertically. In level flight the engine provides no lift.

(Also, usually the term “lift” implies aerodynamic lift, so direct engine thrust would not usually be considered lift even in a vertical climb)

> In the absence of the effect of natural wind, a stationary aircraft will not movement without the thrust of the engine, there will be no velocity without movement, and there will be no lift without velocity.

I would also like to point out that the argument here is fallacious. You are observing that given an aircraft, and given no movement, and given no wind there is no lift. Then you are trying to say that implies that the engine provides the lift. That logic simply does not follow. If A (aircraft) and not B (wind) and not C (motion) and not D (thrust) then not E (lift) does not imply if D then E. It also does not imply if A and D then E.

At a minimum the presence of propositions “not B” and “not C” are particularly problematic for the logic in this specific argument. It is easy to show that if there is either wind (B) or movement (C) then you can have lift (E) without engine thrust (not D). Therefore the engine thrust clearly does not provide lift in general.

However, even without the additional propositions the form of the argument simply is invalid. Suppose if not D then not E were universally true meaning that without engine thrust you never had lift, then it would still not imply that if D then E meaning that engine thrust provides lift. It is simply a fallacious argument at its core.

> Gliders are powered by gravity, so in this case, gravity is the engine. So basically, the engine provides the lift of the aircraft.

Gravity always points down (by definition of “down”) and lift always points up (by definition of “lift”). So no. The only way that you could sort of make that claim is by invoking Newton’s third law to claim that the gravitational force of the glider provides lift for the earth. But that is not the lift we are interested in.

Comment: I gave a graph in the problem, the object moves up under the action of horizontal force. So how does the force of the object moving up come from? Will there be upward force without horizontal thrust?

Comment: A plane that takes off from the ground. Who made it move forward? Engine thrust, engine thrust, engine thrust. Of course, you can also say that manpower can make the plane move forward. But it's human power instead of engine thrust. So we still need the thrust of the engine.

Comment: @engin Zheng said “ A plane that takes off from the ground. Who made it move forward? Engine thrust,” Clearly yes. That does not mean that the engine provides the lift. There are many other things between engine thrust and lift.

Comment: By the way, do you understand the fallacious nature of the argument in your OP?

Comment: As shown in my figure, under gravity, the object slides down the Inclined plane. Where does the lifting force come from? Why doesn't it fall directly through the Inclined plane under the action of gravity?

Comment: Of course, other factors are needed. But a wing alone can't produce lift. Only when the engine is combined with the wing can it produce lift.

Comment: @enbinzheng again, do you understand the fallacy in your argument? Separately, what is required to produce aerodynamic lift is a wing and airflow across the wing. Engine thrust is a reliable way to get airflow, but not the only way. And even when it is the way being used it is still the airflow across the wing that produces the lift

Comment: @enbinzheng I'm not sure how to help you.  There is an easy way to handle this, which handles all cases you can possibly worry about, and there is a hard way which only makes sense in a small number of cases and requires substantial contortions of the terminology.  If you reject the former, eventually we will not be able to help you with the latter.

Comment: Consider this inclined plane case: a 1kg block resting on an inclined plane with friction.  There is sufficient friction such that the block does not slip down.  The inclined plane is providing 9.8N of lift, despite the fact that there is no engine and no movement.  (assuming you choose to call a non-aerodynamic force "lift")

Comment: @CortAmmon-ReinstateMonica Horizontal ground can provide 100% "lift", yes, this is provided by the force of the material structure.  But air has no such structural force, and the wings have to move for lift.

Answer (score 2):

No. Lift is generated by air moving over a wing. **The wing provides the lift.** However, in order for air to rush over the wing either the wing or the air must be in motion relative to the wing. Thus, gravity, an engine, wind (i.e. a parked airplane flipping over), or another source of motion (catapults on aircraft carriers) are necessary (but not responsible) for lift.

Furthermore, to prove your point wrong, imagine a square block with an engine attached. It has no lift. If the engine is providing the lift, this is an obvious contradiction to your claim. You could, however, claim that lift is a means of redirecting kinetic energy which is in most cases is provided by an engine.

Comment: The engine will generate lift even when it is tied with bricks, but it is not as good as the wing.

Answer (score 1):

Find a mountain that just happens to have a runway on a downward slope, with an airplane (hopefully with good brakes) parked at the top of the runway.  Assume the runway is sloped more steeply than the airplane's glide slope.

Hop in, let off the brakes *without starting the engine*.  The airplane will roll down the runway, accelerating as it goes.  Eventually (because the runway is steeper than its glide slope) it will be going fast enough to fly.  Nudge the elevator back, and it'll be airborne.

Enjoy your flight -- and hope that there's a runway someplace in the valley below the mountain.

Comment: Yes, you don't need an engine. You can pull the model plane up with a rope and fly to the sky. It's just that you replaced the engine with manpower. So we still need the engine.

Answer (score -2):

[image]
We all know that the wings have an angle of attack.  Therefore, the wing is an inclined plane, hereinafter referred to as  $A$.

As shown in the figure, the inclination angle of $A$ is $\theta$.  The weight of the aircraft is $W$. $W$ has two components, one component $Wt$ is parallel to $A$ downward, and the other component $W_n$ is perpendicular to $A$ downward.  The horizontal thrust applied by the aircraft engine is $T$. $T$ also has two components, one is an upward component $T_t$ parallel to $A$, and the other is a downward component $T_n$ perpendicular to $A$.  $F$ is the force that $A$ applies to the wing.

It can be known from calculation that when $T = Wtan\theta$, $T_t $ and $W_t$ are two quantities of equal magnitude and opposite directions.  They are balanced.  On the other hand, the aircraft will accelerate the movement under the action of $T$, and finally make $F$ and $W_n + T_n$ balance.

From the formula $T = Wtan\theta$, as long as $\theta <\frac{\pi}{4}$, then $T <W$.  Due to the angle of attack of the wings $\alpha<<\frac{\pi}{4} $, the aircraft can cruise with thrust levels much smaller than the weight of the aircraft.

So we can say that $T$ provides lift.  Because in horizontal flight, the lift $L = \frac{T}{tan\theta}= -W$.  Without $T$, there is no $L$.

Of course, the actual situation is more complicated, and factors such as stall, airfoil, and low pressure at the top of the wing must be considered.